# How to get contents of a variable in IPython REPL when debugging?

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, ipython, spyder

I'm using python 3 with Spyder. Consider following code:

```
def fun(x,y):
    n,m = len(x), len(y)
    pass #set breakpoint on this line

x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]

fun(x,y)
```

When I set a break point on line three and run the debugger I expect to be able to evaluate both `n` and `m` in the debugger console. While typing `m` (then enter) returns a number as expected, typing `n` just shows prints the current state of the debugger. I assume `n` is some special debugger command.

- Where can I find *all* the commands I can use in the debugger console?
- How can I still print variables that have the same name as some of these commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the commands here in the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pdb.html

The command `p <expression>` can be used to evaluate and print a python exprerssion, so in this case you have to use `p n` to get the contents of `n`.